# MS Word equations don't permit subscripts or superscripts

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using Word in MS Office Professional Plus 2016.  I am able to create an equation by clicking on the equation icon in the "insert" tab of the ribbon.  But once inside the equation box, subscripts and superscripts are disabled.  In the font section of the "home" tab the sub and superscript icons are grayed out AND the shortcuts to sub and superscripts do no work (if I'm not in the equation box, the sub and superscripts work fine).  I should also note that once in the equation box, I don't see the ribbon full of equation symbols which I see on the Word tutorial videos about equation writing.  What's going on?

Comment: Use underscore for subscript and ^ for superscript

Answer (score 1):

Could you share the detailed version/build number of Word 2016 you are using? You can   [update your Office to the latest version to have a check](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/update-office-with-microsoft-update-f59d3f9d-bd5d-4d3b-a08e-1dd659cf5282).

[image]

I can reproduce what you see that sub and superscript icons are grayed out on the Home tab. I think it's by design because we can use the sub and superscript icons on Equation Tool - Design tab instead.

[image]

If you don't see [the Equation Tool - Design tab](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/write-an-equation-or-formula-1d01cabc-ceb1-458d-bc70-7f9737722702#ID0EAACAAA=Edit_equations) when you click Insert > Equation, you can enable it by customize ribbon:

[image]

Comment: to add, superscript and subscript following a symbol (like a letter or something) can be done with an underscore or a caret as a shorthand